# Puppet fetching specific value of a key from hash

Tags: puppet, hiera

My hiera entries -

```
mysqlconfig::custom_mysql_options:
   mysqld:
     replicate-ignore-db: 'test'
     server-id: 12
     datadir: '/data/mysql_data'
```

I want to get the value of datadir in my puppet module. Please let me know what is the syntax I need to use to fetch this value. I tried something as follows but it doesn't work.

```
$datadir = hiera('mysqlconfig::custom_mysql_options[datadir]')

 file { "$datadir":
 ensure => directory,
 owner  => 'mysql',
 group  => 'mysql',
 mode   => '0755',
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should read the key, which is a hash, and after that read the value within the hash:

```
$custom_options = hiera_hash("mysqlconfig::custom_mysql_options")
$datadir        = $custom_options["mysqld"]["datadir"]
```